# How to call a parameter into a js from servlet

Tags: javascript, java, sql

I want to pass value of a parameter from servlet into `js` function.
Here is my java code:

```
double nota = rs1.getDouble(1);
request.setAttribute("nota",nota);
```

Here is how I call into `js`:

```
<script>
rate (${nota})
</script>
```

But I'm getting this error:

Multiple annotations found at this line:

```
- Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
 tokens
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
 construct(s)
```

Could anyone help me? I' m new to `js`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `""` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        rate("${nota}"); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scriptlet:

```
<script> var rate= "${nota}"; </script>
```

You can use an input hidden too.